# Azure Devops REST API with .NET 6 C#. Push a zipped folder to a repo

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to push a zipped folder contents to a azure repo using REST API call. I am using visual studio 2022 version with .NET6 C# code.
below is the code piece:

```
var fileContent = await new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(folderZipUrl);
var fileBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent);

//json = $"{{ \"ref\": \"main\", \"path\": \".\", \"message\": \"Initial commit\", \"content\": \"{fileBase64String}\" }}";

var jsonObj = new
{
    refUpdates = "refs/heads/main",
    path = "./",
    message = "Initial commit",
    content = fileBase64String
};
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonObj);

// push the new file
baseUrl = $"{baseUrl}/pushes?api-version=6.0";
response = await httpclient.PostAsync(baseUrl, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

This code returns a response of Status code 400. Bad Request. I also tried declaring json content as per the commented line no 4.

I am creating an repository using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

but the response is not the same as sample one given in the documentation. There are no fields for id or project in the actual response.

```
{
  "id": "76b510af-7910-4a96-9902-b978d6226bee",
  "name": "forkRepository",
  "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/MyFirstProject/_apis/git/repositories/76b510af-7910-4a96-9902-b978d6226bee",
  "project": {
    "id": "3b046b6a-d070-4cd5-ad59-2eace5d05b90",
.
.
.
.
.
```

Could anyone tell me what is the problematic code here.

Comment: You should **not** put binaries into version control. What are you attempting to accomplish by doing this? What is your end-goal?

Comment: @DanielMann for now, I am trying to add a zipped folder's content into the devops repo.

Comment: Yes, but **why**?

Comment: @DanielMann So that I can access the code while creating pipelines and some other process.

Comment: The correct approach is to publish pipeline artifacts and/or Azure Artifacts, not push binaries into source control. Pushing binaries into version control, *especially* into Git, will quickly make your repository balloon to gigabytes in size and become completely unusable.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround to store shared build results, consider the following approaches:

1. Publish your build artifacts as usual.. then download them in other pipelines through [DownloadPipelineArtifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines)
2. Publish your build results in universal artifacts. Check this link: [Publish and download universal packages with Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I don't want to store the build results, but instead store the scripts of resources and yaml build files in repo. Through the stored yaml file, I'll create a pipeline.

Comment: I am also creating the repository using the API call. so maybe the repositoryId is the issue, the create call response is not same as the sample one given in the documentation. I am editing the question too.

Answer (score -1):

Check the request here: [Add a binary file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#add-a-binary-file)

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "1380164a8118686087e38ce91f36b24b58c2df02"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added new image file.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/images/people/default.jpg"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcHBw8KCwkMEQ..........",
            "contentType": "base64encoded"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And powershell example here: [UpdateBinaryGitFile.ps1](https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomPSTasks/UpdateBinaryGitFile.ps1)

Comment: how do I get the oldObjectId dynamically?

Comment: @neeraj you can use [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP). The sample in the UpdateBinaryGitFile.ps1 in my answer.